# grafana loki operator logs all come prepended with 'stderr f'

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki

Picture below, why is it stderr f appears here? My logs are all in json format as expected. This is very annoying

[image]

Comment: Kubernetes formats logs as `<timestamp> <stream> <F?> <message>` (mount `/var/logs/containers` in a container and tail any log file). You need to parse it with regex and extract the message itself.

Comment: This is very useful to know. Do you know if this behavior changed in Kubernetes? We recently upgraded from k8s 1.18 to 1.21 and I am wonder if that is related.

Answer (score 2):

Those are cri-o containerd log format. With the k8s upgrade you probably switched to containerd too and is affecting log format.

Comment: This does a good job explaining what needs to be changed: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentbit-containerd-cri-o-json-log